# problems in the running the rails server after updating to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I updated my rails from 3 to 4 and ruby to version 2. I tried running rails s after running the updates. What is the error?

```
/home/aravind/Documents/dev/ptl/config/application.rb:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_resource/railtie (LoadError)
from /home/aravind/Documents/dev/ptl/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2I .0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please provide the code located around `config/application.rb:7` There is a good chance that you have a `require 'active_resource'` statement. Since Rails 4, `active_resource` is not part of `rails` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

in `aplication.rb` comment this line:

```
require "active_resource/railtie"
```

if you have it, if not I'll just remove my answer but this fixed my problem a few days ago.